# What is it called when you "justify" things to yourself like this?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Recently, it became evident that the very anticipated "Analogue Pocket" device (modern hardware simulator of Game Boy/Game Boy Color/Game Boy Advance) would not become available for normal people to buy until 2023. Only influential reviewers and people who had pre-ordered (and paid up-front) long ago have got their units.

I became so angry about this that I instead ordered a much more expensive, fully hand-restored and enhanced (better screen, etc.) Game Boy Color from a company specializing in this kind of thing. And now, after receiving and setting it up, I no longer want the Analogue Pocket. Or do I?

I have convinced myself that I don't want one, at least. The downsides mentioned in reviews were like beautiful music to my ears while I was waiting for my modded GBC. But maybe I secretly still wish that I had an Analogue Pocket?

My question is: what is this called? Is there a single word or a phrase describing this kind of "self-trickery" to justify me spending more on something technically inferior but which was at least possible for me to get my hands on?

Comment: This, perhaps? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology)

Comment: Is it *sour grapes*?

Comment: 'Rationalisation' with the 'trying to convince yourself (and often succeeding in doing so) that your choices are justified' is certainly the answer here, but has been given before in a very similar ELU question.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Yosef's suggestion: the phrase "sour grapes" is often used as a shorthand allusion to [Aesop's fable of "The fox and the grapes,"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Grapes) in which a fox tries to reach some grapes, is unable to, and tells himself that they were sour anyway—rationalizing the unattainable as undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

This is called **Rationalization**.

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of possibilities.

One is *buyer's remorse*. From The Free Dictionary:

> Buyer's remorse is the sense of regret after having made a purchase.
> It is frequently associated with the purchase of an expensive item
> such as a vehicle or real estate.
>
> Buyer's remorse is thought to stem from cognitive dissonance,
> specifically post-decision dissonance, that arises when a person must
> make a difficult decision, such as a heavily invested purchase between
> two similarly appealing alternatives. Factors that affect buyer's
> remorse may include: resources invested, the involvement of the
> purchaser, whether the purchase is compatible with the purchaser's
> goals, feelings encountered post-purchase that include regret.

I recommend reading the remainder of The Free Dictionary's description of buyer's remorse: https://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/buyer%27s+remorse